# I used Expanded and still got overflowed problem Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, responsive

I am trying to make my app responsive and I noticed that there is a problem in some screen sizes , I'm already using Expanded for the Container that including the question

[image: app]

And I tried using Expanded for Answers too and flex: 2; for the question and that's what I got

appPic2

[image]

What it should be like

[image]

```
 Expanded(

                      child: Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 220.0,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            top: 5, bottom: 0, left: 30.0, right: 30.0),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            horizontal: 0.0, vertical: 0.0),
                      
                        child: Center(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                _questions[_questionIndex]['question'],
                                textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                  fontFamily: "Tajawal",
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                ),
                              ),
```

Answer Code

```dart
...(_questions[_questionIndex]['answers']
                    as List<Map<String, Object>>)
                        .map(
                          (answer) =>
                          Answer(
                            answerText: answer['answerText'],
                            answerColor: answerWasSelected
                                ? answer['score']
                                ? Colors.green[400]
                                : Colors.red[400]
                                : null,
                            
                          ),
```

and this is for answer in another file

```
InkWell(
      onTap: answerTap,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 30.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        
        child: Text(
          answerText,
          

          

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code?

Comment: or the code itself

Comment: sorry , already included you can check

Comment: could you provide a screen where the overflow appears?

Comment: its in the first image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is you providing a `height` for the `container` which has the `text` as a child
and the text is long

so if you want the `container` to be with fixed height then you should wrap the `column` widget with `singleChildScrollView`

or if you want the `container` to take the question space , then remove the `height` property from the `container` and wrap the column with `Expanded`

Comment: understandable , thanks

Comment: https://ibb.co/1mtNNfH
I have one more question , how to make this Row fixed position in the top ? its always move when container gets bigger or smaller

Comment: and look when i choose bigger screen https://ibb.co/hdJ9Ctf

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min
```

To the column widget. Now the column has no bounds

Comment: With expanded in the answer and the question or with only in question ?

Comment: I tried it , same problem

Comment: Whats the parent of expanded widget?

Comment: ```
Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
```

Comment: Wrap the column with a sized box with height and width same as the device.

Comment: nothing happened